# How do I see status of specific services in an array

Tags: c#

I am trying to see the status of multiple services in my string array.

The service may not always exist on the machines I will be using it on hence the `try`

Code:

```
    public string[] service = { "MSSQL$AMTECHFASTTEST", "SQLBrowser" };
    public void stopService()
    {
        int i = 0;
        ServiceController[] scServices;
        scServices = ServiceController.GetServices(service[i]);

        try
        {
                foreach (ServiceController services in scServices)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(service[i]+" " + services.Status.ToString(), "Service Status");
                    i++;
                }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error");
        }
    }
```

I think it is the `ServiceController.GetServices(service[i])` line that is causing the errors, but I cannot work it out.

Thanks,

Comment: In your code `i` is `-1` and therefor _out of range_ if used as an array index.

Comment: Thanks Rene, however this still doesn't fix my issue. - I have just edited it into my code.

Comment: You've not told us what your issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ServiceController.GetServices(string machineName)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s21fd6th(v=vs.110).aspx) method retrieves the services running at the host *`machineName`*.

If you want to get the services that are running on the *same* machine as your program, use `ServiceController.GetServices()` without a parameter.

So I think what you want to do is something like this:

```
public string[] wantedServices = { "MSSQL$AMTECHFASTTEST", "SQLBrowser" };
public void stopService()
{
    ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices()
                                      .Where(svc => wantedServices.Contains(svc.ServiceName))
                                      .ToArray();

    try
    {
        foreach (ServiceController svc in services)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"{svc.ServiceName} {svc.Status}", "Service Status");                    
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error");
    }
}
```

This gets all the services on the current machine that have names contained in your `wantedServices` array (I changed some variable names for clarity).

Comment: Thanks Rene, perfecto!